# How can i get my files to be opened?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi there im working on a function that merges two separate .txt files and outputs a personalized letter. The problem is, is that i can include my text within the funciton module and it works perfectly. But when i try to open them in the function and to be used by the function i get this

error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nathandavis9752/CP104/davi0030_a10/src/q2_function.py", line 25, in 
    data = cleanData(q2)
  File "/Users/nathandavis9752/CP104/davi0030_a10/src/q2_function.py", line 17, in cleanData
    return [item.strip().split('\n\n') for item in query.split('--')]
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'

code:

```
letter = open('letter.txt', 'r')

q2 = open('q2.txt', 'r')

def cleanData(query):
    return [item.strip().split('\n\n') for item in query.split('--')]

def writeLetter(template, variables, replacements):
    # replace ith variable with ith replacement variable
    for i in range(len(variables)):
        template = template.replace(variables[i], replacements[i]) 
    return template

data = cleanData(q2)

print (data)

variables = ['[fname]', '[lname]', '[street]', '[city]']

letters = [writeLetter(letter, variables, person) for person in data]

for i in letters:
    print (i)
```

## q2.txt file:

```
Michael

dawn

lock hart ln

Dublin

--

kate

Nan

webster st

king city

--

raj

zakjg

late Road

Toronto

--

dave

porter

Rock Ave

nobleton
```

## letter.txt file:

```
[fname] [lname]
[street]
[city]

Dear [fname]:

   As a fellow citizen of [city], you and all your neighbours 
on [street] are invited to a celebration this Saturday at 
[city]'s Central Park. Bring beer and food!
```

Comment: Remember to read the error. The important part is the last part: `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to split a file buffer rather than a string.

```
def cleanData(query):
    return [item.strip().split('\n\n') for item in query.read().split('--')]
```

Comment: Still not working...

Error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nathandavis9752/CP104/davi0030_a10/src/q2_function.py", line 31, in <module>
    letters = [writeLetter(letter, variables, person) for person in data]
  File "/Users/nathandavis9752/CP104/davi0030_a10/src/q2_function.py", line 22, in writeLetter
    template = template.replace(variables[i], replacements[i]) 
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nathandavis9752/CP104/davi0030_a10/src/q2_function.py", line 25, in <module>
    data = cleanData(q2)
  File "/Users/nathandavis9752/CP104/davi0030_a10/src/q2_function.py", line 17, in cleanData
    return [item.strip().split('\n\n') for item in query.read().split('--')]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: @stacker Keep your code as is, meaning revert the `q2` variable. Then change the function to this. Use your original code then switch the function out.